# Docker push on OS/X very slow - and seems to push layers that have already been pushed

Tags: docker

My docker pushes have been show, and then timing out with TLS errors - I've restarted docker before each push, which seems to have improved things.

What is puzzling me is that it seems to be re-doing work it has already done.

Here are two screenshots. In the first, you can see that the layer 2c2153fbd032 has been pushed. I'd expect it then to confirm this and not have to reload it. However, it goes to 'retrying'.

Any suggestions as to what the problem might be? I've now had this one push failing for three days.

[image: Docker push - showing 8.102MB uploaded - should be complete]

[image: Docker push - a few seconds later - now showing 'Retrying in 1 second']

Comment: Did you upgrade OSX recently?

Comment: I start to have the same problem, I am running on macosx Catalina. I also try to update to the latest docker but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I've not fixed it completely, but this advice seems to be useful:

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/621

It recommends creating a .json file with a smaller number of concurrent uploads.

Answer (score 0):

"you can see that the layer 2c2153fbd032 has been pushed"

> no or you would actually see "Pushed".

It is therefore not surprising docker tries to push again that same layer.

It can depend on your docker version: [1.10 on Mac had that issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21563)

> Docker version 1.10.3 on my OS X also had this issue.
>   It's gone after update to 1.11 and pushed layers are detected correctly as "`Layer already exists`".